# Running into KeyError in Program

Tags: python, python-3.x

The program that I am working on requires that we build a minimally perfect hash-table of key words, and then use that table to search a text file for the amount of times each key word appears in the file. To do this, we are required to use Cichelli's method.

Here is the list of key words, and the dict of the starting and ending letters:

```
{'h': 3, 'y': 4, 'j': 1, 'n': 6, 't': 5, 'g': 2, 'd': 2, 'a': 2, 's': 1, 'o': 4, 'w': 3, 'l': 1, 'f': 3, 'e': 1, 'r': 2, 'm': 2, 'u': 1, 'i': 3}

[('nation', 12, 6), ('today', 9, 5), ('to', 9, 2), ('in', 9, 2), ('demonstration', 8, 13), ('down', 8, 4), ('what', 8, 4), ('greatest', 7, 8), ('history', 7, 7), ('happy', 7, 5), ('join', 7, 4), ('of', 7, 2), ('with', 6, 4), ('the', 6, 3), ('our', 6, 3), ('go', 6, 2), ('freedom', 5, 7), ('you', 5, 3), ('for', 5, 3), ('will', 4, 4), ('am', 4, 2), ('as', 3, 2), ('i', 3, 1)]
```

After those two have been built, I initialize an empty list to store the hash table in. My issue is when I try to run the function below,

```
def wordPlacement(hash, word_record, Tsize, g):
    max = int(Tsize/2)
    attempt = 0
    success = False
    while attempt <= max:
        word = word_record[0]
        length = word_record[2]
        g_first = g[word[0]]
        g_last = g[word[length - 1]] if length != 1 else 0
        h = (length + g_first + g_last) % Tsize
        if hash[h] == '':
            hash[h] = word
            success = True
            g[word[0]] -= attempt
            break
        else:
            g[word[0]] += 1
            attempt += 1
    return success, hash
```

with the empty list being hash, the key words and their weights being word_record, Tsize being the number of unique keywords, and g being the list of letters, I run into a KeyError that says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PyCharm Files/COP 4530 - HW#1.py", line 145, in <module>
    wordPlacement(hash, keyWordValues, numOfKeyWords, letters)
  File "D:/PyCharm Files/COP 4530 - HW#1.py", line 15, in wordPlacement
    g_first = g[word[0]]
KeyError: 'nation'
```

I have no clue as to what is causing this, so any help that points me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "no clue"? Well, do you know what a `KeyError` is, first of all? Why do you think the exception traceback includes the lines from your code that it does? What do you think is the relevance of it telling you the `: 'nation'` part? Did you try checking the values of variables in that part of the code, to make sure that each line is doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: Can you show the function call with representative values for `hash`, `word_record`, `g`?

Comment: wordPlacement(hash, keyWordValues, numOfKeyWords, g_letters)
hash = [ ] **|**
keyWordValues = The list with the length and weight of the word **|**
numOfKeyWords = The number of unique keywords, so 23 in this case. **|**
g_letters = The letter and how many times it occurs as either a word's beginning or ending. **|**
I do apologize for how my question sounds. This is my first time in Python doing this type of work.

Comment: Before the line that gives the error, add a simple `print( “word[0]=”,word[0])` and then `print( “g=“,g )` so you see the actual values that are being used. You will find that `word[0]` isn’t a key in `g`. Now you need to figure out why that is the case. If you can’t use a debugger, simply add some print statements.